# Read image labels from a csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I have a dataset of medical images (`.dcm`) which I can read into `TensorFlow` as a batch. However, the problem that I am facing is that the labels of these images are in a `.csv`. The `.csv` file contains two columns - `image_path` (location of the image) and `image_labels` (0 for no; 1 for yes). I wanted to know how I can read the labels into a `TensorFlow` dataset batch wise. I am using the following code to load the images batch wise:-

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_io as tfio

def process_image(filename):
    image_bytes = tf.io.read_file(filename)
    image = tf.squeeze(
        tfio.image.decode_dicom_image(image_bytes, on_error='strict', dtype=tf.uint16),
        axis = 0
    )
    x = tfio.image.decode_dicom_data(image_bytes, tfio.image.dicom_tags.PhotometricInterpretation)
    image = (image - tf.reduce_min(image))/(tf.reduce_max(image) - tf.reduce_min(image))
    if(x == "MONOCHROME1"):
        image = 1 - image
    image = image*255
    image = tf.cast(tf.image.resize(image, (512, 512)),tf.uint8)
    return image

# train_images is a list containing the locations of .dcm images
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(train_images)
dataset = dataset.map(process_image, num_parallel_calls=4).batch(50)
```

Hence, I can load the images into the `TensorFlow` dataset. But I would like to know how I can load the image labels batch wise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this instead of the last two lines should work:

```py
#train_labels is a list of labels for each image in the same order as in train_images

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_images, train_labels))
dataset = dataset.map(lambda x,y : (process_image(x), y), num_parallel_calls=4).batch(50)
```

now the `dataset` can be passed to your network's `.fit()`, `.predict()` and other methods:

```
model.fit(dataset, epochs=epochs, callbacks=callbacks)
```

Alternatively, you can create a second dataset containing the labels and then combine two datasets with [tf.data.Dataset.zip()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#zip). It works similarly to the python's native `zip`.

I prefer the first method since It feels a bit cleaner to me + I can, for example, shuffle the filenames/labels and only then parse the files instead of doing the opposite.